# Checkpoint VPN issue: Connectivity with VPN service is lost

Tags: windows, vpn, checkpoint

I have installed SecuRemote Client of checkpoint E75.30 on my computer running Windows 8.

When I try to perform any of SecuRemote functions e.g. See client, Add client, See options etc. it gives the error "Connectivity with VPN service is lost"
I checked if the Check Point Endpoint Security VPN service would start automatically, but it did not.

When I try to start it manually I get "Error 1075: Dependency service does not exist or has been marked for deletion", however Dependency service is DHCP client which is running fine.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? Having the same problem!

Comment: No, I didn't unfortunately...

Answer (score 14):

I managed to fix this issue on Windows 7 by going to

1. Control Panel
2. Programs and Features
3. Check Point Endpoint Security VPN
4. right click
5. repair

Comment: This worked for me!!!

Answer (score 13):

I managed to solve it by going into 'services' (start menu, type services) and noticed that checkpoint service was disabled. once you enable it, you should be all set.

Comment: in my case the services were running, but restart solved

Answer (score 8):

It's happening a lot in windows 10 updates. To solve, just found the Check point services, there are two, and start then.
In msconfig, check the services to start with windows.
I don´t know why, windows 10 updates disable this services.

Comment: In my case, I think I broke this by disabling CheckPoint from startup in Windows 10 Task Manager, which caused CheckPoint's service not to be running. It's stupid that CheckPoint doesn't start the service itself, but at least manually starting it helped me. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this.but the service (check point end point security vpn) does not start

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to this problem.

I had McAfee installed on a new laptop (win 10 x64). Installed VPN, Error connecting. Uninstalled McAfee. Error. Repaired Checkpoint VPN. Error. Restart and repair. Error. Always got the error *"Unable to load Virtual Network Adapter"*.

I am a contractor to a client who uses Checkpoint so cannot view checkpoint's KB articles. So cannot view any of their solutions. Client cannot give me login.

So. Finally figured this out:

1. Click **Start**, click **Run**, type `cmd.exe`, and then press **ENTER**.
2. Type `set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1`, and then press **ENTER**.
3. Type `Start DEVMGMT.MSC`, and then press **ENTER**.
4. Click **View**, and then click **Show Hidden Devices**.
5. Expand the **Network Adapters** tree.
6. Right click on **Check Point Virtual Network Adapter For Endpoint VPN Client** select **Disable** and then again and **Enable**
7. Attempt to connect now.

Thanks to [This Link](http://www.extropy.com/forums/knowledge-bases-extropedia/microsoft/how-remove-hidden-network-adapters) for steps 1-5.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I was able to resolve this by going to control panel, services, and then I started all of the Check Point services (there are 4 and 2 were down)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are still getting this error, or if you have resolved it, but I was having the same problem and found this question.

I was getting the same error message, but I was able to restart the service without any errors.

Here are the dependant services that I have running:

- Check Point Virtual Network Adapter - Apollo
- DHCP Client

DHCP Client is dependant on the following:

- Ancillary Function Driver for Winstock
- NetIO Legacy TDI Support Driver
- Network Store Interface Service

Have you checked if those services are running? Try restart them if possible.

[This page](http://www.kapilarya.com/the-dependency-service-does-not-exist-or-has-been-marked-for-deletion) recommends deleting the services and restarting your machine. I would create a restore point before you try deleting any services.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by Right click >>> repair on the file : CheckPointVPN.msi .

Comment: did not help...

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem and resolved.
* If you use LAN connection, try it by disconnecting the LAN cable and connecting to WiFi.
* If not works, try it by connecting via a Dongle or Mobile Hotspot.

(LAN connection and WiFi of the company get it's proxy and proxy prevents the VPN)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but fix this simply with rightclick->run as administrator

Comment: Please restrict your answers to technical content. ASCII art isn't helping your readers.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the BIOS settings and uncheck Auto Switch Network Adapters